# How Access Token work

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure, access-token

I am going through **Web Api in Asp.Net** using **Visual Studio 2013**.I am using Asp.Net Web Api Template.I am able to build a simple client that can register and login with the API.I got Bearer Token When user login and i send this token in header for accessing data from my API.Now i wanted to know how this Token in get/post request is working in API side.

When i made this API work with Windows Azure Storage I have not seen any table that saves these token corresponding to users.so where these token goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for these particular tokens, however other token frameworks that I used (DotnetOpenAuth) just encrypt the username and access scope and create a ticket out of it.

It is similar to what the Forms Authentication module does. There is also no table to map issued cookies to users and this is because the cookie can just be decrypted at the server side.

Think about the token as a standalone encrypted information rather than an internal id to data that has to be persisted at the server side.